# Redirect upload to public/upload

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I want force website redirect from https://tutorials.originersmc.com/uploads/ to https://tutorials.originersmc.com/public/uploads/

I know is using .htaccess, but I don't know code.

Any answer to add that redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it redirects the user to public/uploads when the folder /uploads is requested

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^uploads$ https://tutorials.originersmc.com/public/uploads/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Comment: No problem! If this anwser worked for you, please mark it as correct by pressing the check mark

Answer (score 1):

I'd add this line to the `.htaccess` file when your site supports relative links:

```
Redirect 301 /uploads /public/uploads
```

For absolute links use this:

```
Redirect 301 /uploads/ https://tutorials.originersmc.com/public/uploads/
```

When someone accesses `/uploads` he will be redirected to `/public/uploads`

Make sure to edit the `.htaccess` file with a proper text editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::redirect('/uploads', '/public/uploads', 301);
```

Does the same when defined in **web.php**